# With Dask under Python, how can I assign() with case_when column assignments?

Tags: python, dask

In R, this would be the equivalent I'm trying to achieve:

```
library(tidytable)
df |>
  mutate(new_column = case_when(x > y ~ 'x_is_larger',
                                y > x ~ 'y_is_larger',
                                x == y ~ 'x_y_equal',
                                TRUE ~ NA),
         another_column = 123)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't like to do your work for you, you are expected to come with specific things you have tried and a description of how it didn't do what you expected. I, for one, don't even know what the code above achieves.